# Discord.py having two different file-reading variables acting slightly different from one another

Tags: python, discord.py

new to stack so bear with me.

I'm currently making a bot for discord that uses .txt files to save the amount of times people on the server say insensitive words, with the goal to put a stop to it. I also have a main text file (info.txt) that stores the total combined score.

```
 h = open(str(message.author) + ".txt", 'r')
auth = h.read()
h.close()
if auth == "" or auth == None:
    h = open(str(message.author) + ".txt", 'w')
    h.write("0")
    h.close()
    auth = "0"
auth = int(float(auth))

f = open("info.txt", 'r')
nwordCount = f.read()
f.close()
if nwordCount == "" or nwordCount == None:
    f = open("info.txt", "w")
    f.write("0")
    f.close()
nwordCount = int(float(nwordCount))
```

Yes, I know how bad it looks, I've just started looking into python and for some reason this monstrosity worked. As you can see, both auth and nwordCount are structured the same way, besides the auth = "0" not being mirrored for nwordCount.

```
for n in slurs:
    if n in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('HEY!')
        print("+1")
        nwordCount += 1
        nwordCount = str(nwordCount)
        auth += 1
        auth = str(auth)
        f = open("info.txt", 'w')
        f.write(nwordCount)
        f.close()
        g = open(str(message.author) + ".txt", "w")
        g.write(auth)
        g.close()
```

For some reason, the info.txt file always goes up by one. Any other file, however (the ones that are generated for each user) goes from 0 to 1, but then stays at one no many how many times they fit the condition. my assumption is either the way I'm using the file methods (which, as you can see, I don't know very well) or the way I assign the files for new users is the issue, but I'm not too sure. Any help is appreciated!

Quick edit: I also have a method that makes the user's file the first time they type, which looks like this:

```
def fileMaker(message):
g = open(str(message.author) + ".txt", "w")
g.close()
```

I dont think this is the issue, but it might help?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the solution. removed the if statements and added the initial zero value to my filemaker.